# Getting started with VPS

Tags: google-project-tango

I would like to start looking into VPS (Visual Positioning System) that was announced at Google IO this year, but finding information on how to partner or get started is not easy to come by.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VPS Closed Beta Sign-up form:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf2-lNl_eXP0AbclA0ZCYiSVWKw_6q7V80qsMnwj3zpDFeMaA/viewform?c=0&w=1